# How do I get my Dash app graph to update with the dropdown items provided?

Tags: dropdown, plotly-dash

I'm using a csv file with beer sales from a craft brewery.  The items are categorized by "Minor" and "Major" type, as there are some non-alcoholic products for sale.  But I'm not sure how to get the bar graph to update with just the Major category type...

Ideally, I'm trying to show the sales data by Minor category for each of the selected Major categories.  The code is provided here:

```
# Import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go 

file_loc = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Barbj379/Two_Ton/main/Item%20Sales%20Report.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file_loc)

# Create a dash application
app = JupyterDash(__name__)


app.layout= html.Div(children=[
 # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
    html.Div([ 
        html.H1(children='Two Ton Dash'),
           html.Div(children='''
            Sales report of last fiscal quarter.
            
        '''),
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='graph0'),
       html.Label(["Category",
                dcc.Dropdown(
                id='category-dropdown', clearable=False,
                value='ALCOHOL', options=[
                    {'label': c, 'value': c}
                    for c in df['Major Category'].unique()])
                ]),
        ]),
    ])
])


# Callback function that automatically updates the tip-graph based on chosen colorscale
@app.callback(
    Output('graph0', 'figure'),
    [Input("category-dropdown", "value")]
)
def update_figure(Category):
    new_df = df.groupby(['Minor Category', 'Item Name'])['Net Sales'].sum().reset_index()
    new_df.reset_index()
    fig=px.bar(
        new_df, x="Minor Category", y="Net Sales",  color="Item Name",
        color_continuous_scale=Category,
        title="Items")
    return fig
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
# Create an app layout
```

When I run the code provided, there's a bar-chart displaying the sum of Item Name sales, grouped by Minor Category type; but the dropdown menu doesn't filter anything out.  Apologies for being such a noob!

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your data with `Category` value before groupby it. You could update your callback as below:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph0', 'figure'),
    [Input("category-dropdown", "value")]
)
def update_figure(Category):
    new_df = df[df['Major Category']==Category]
    new_df = new_df.groupby(['Minor Category', 'Item Name'])['Net Sales'].sum().reset_index()
    new_df.reset_index()
    fig=px.bar(
        new_df, x="Minor Category", y="Net Sales",  color="Item Name",
        color_continuous_scale=Category,
        title="Items")
    return fig
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, much appreciated!